# restrict objects on models for custom user groups

Tags: django, django-models

my problem is i want to restrict some objects in my models to custom group users.
is there any way for that?

```
class Ad(models.Model):
    submit_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField(default=now_plus_30_days)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
```

for example i want to group 1 cant accsess to see the publish_date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, I am using it in many projects.

Just use [Django Guardian](https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian)

It is a tool to restrict objects to users or to groups. By default admins will always have full access.